# How are the "seven different ways" from Sahih Bukhari, book 61, hadith 513 reflected in Quran?

Tags: quran, sahih-bukhari, qiraat, uloom-al-quran

[Sahih Bukhari, volume 6, book 61, hadith 513](http://www.gowister.com/sahihbukhari-6-513.html) (emphasis mine):

> Narrated 'Abdullah bin 'Abbas:
>
> Allah's Apostle said, "Gabriel recited the Qur'an to me in one way.
>   Then I requested him (to read it in another way), and continued asking
>   him to recite it in other ways, and he recited it in several ways till
>   **he ultimately recited it in seven different ways**."

Since I don't know of seven different versions of the Quran, this seems to be in conflict to the belief in immutability of the Quran. The hadith [should be held authenthic at least for Sunnis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2423/835), so ruling it out is not an option. It is also supported by other hadiths, like [the next one](http://www.gowister.com/sahihbukhari-6-514.html), which specifies that at least [Surat Al-Furqan](https://quran.com/25) was allowed to be recited in several different ways, making explanation by [re-revelation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16836/835) problematic. "Quran" in this context doesn't necessary mean the whole book, but it still seems that at least few verses should be included in more than one wording.

Comment: A detailed discussion on the same matter is here.
https://islamqa.info/en/5142

Comment: I think this is adressed in poste with the [tag:qiraat] like https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/what-are-the-readings-qiraat-of-quran?lq=1, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37700/examples-of-verses-of-the-quran-with-two-different-readings and  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30508/different-versions-of-arabic-quran?noredirect=1&lq=1 etc.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25492/835 answers my question quite well. Could you make a full answer by adapting it to this question? Or you suggest closing this question as a duplicate instead?

Comment: Usually we would declare that as a duplicate post unless you make out what points I exactly should address?

Comment: In fact this should be closed as a duplicate. As a Christian, I don't know the Islamic terminology - I wouldn't have asked the question if I knew of qiraat before. I don't have the previlege to close it myself, so you can close it.